# What does "get to be" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

https://www.lingq.com/lesson/lesson-19-taking-risks-431414/

> Hey, you know I didn't **get to be** where I am today without taking some
>   risks.

What does "get to be" mean in the above context? I guess it means "reach", but I am not sure. and I need some simple examples in plain English of using "get to be".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Hey, you know I didn't get to be where I am today without taking some risks.

*= same as =*

> Hey, you know I didn't **acquire the position that I am in** today without taking some risks.

...implying that the speaker is in a "high position" with the company they work for, and possibly implies that they earn lots of money.

---

After thinking more about it,

"I get to" implies a good, positive thing that is going to happen to me (either *now* or *in the future*).

It is the opposite of "I have to" which implies **I am not happy** about something that I *need* to do (either *now* or *in the future*).

> I **get to** fly an airplane tomorrow!   :-)
>
> I **get to** go home and see my children now!  :-)

...as opposed to:

> I **have to** go to the dentist tomorrow.  :-(
>
> I **have to** go home and see my children now.  :-(

Comment: dear ashleedawg: thanks for your answer. but I don't know the strange phrase in your answer, I mean "I are not" is a mistake or not. If it is not a mistake would you please inform me about that.

Comment: @AR-AM -- You are correct; that was a mistake.  **Good Job!**  You're ready to start teaching English!  :-)   ...the words _"I are"_  should _never_ be next to each other.